# sh: 2: 1: not found - pass multiple php arguments to bash script

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a simple bash script which i call from my php code to find out the version of my apache and nginx.

```
$webroot = getcwd();

function get_version($name)
{
    global $webroot;

    switch ($name)
    {
        case "apache":
            $path   = shell_exec("whereis apachectl | awk '{ print $2 }'");
            $version = shell_exec("sudo $webroot/scripts/get_version $path 1 2>&1");
            break;
        case "nginx":
            $path = shell_exec("whereis nginx | awk '{ print $2 }'");
            $version = shell_exec("sudo $webroot/scripts/get_version $path 2 2>&1");
        default:
            echo "error";
    }

    return $version;
}
```

As you can see i call my bash script with two arguments passed. The path and a integer number which i use in my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

_x=""
_programm=$1
_nr=$2

if [ "$_nr" -eq "1" ] ; then
    _x=$($_programm -v 2>/dev/null | grep -i 'version' | awk -F/ '{ print $4 }')
elif [ "$_nr" -eq "2" ] ; then
    _x=$($_programm -v 2>&1 | awk -F/ '{ print $2 }')
fi

cd $(pwd)
echo $_x
```

Output of function:

```
get_version("apache");     OUTPUT:     sh: 2: 1: not found
get_version("nginx");      OUTPUT:     sh: 2: 2: not found
```

But if i execute the bash script in the terminal, then it works and i get the version number as output, i tried it both with user `root` and `www-data`, both worked. The bash script is also entered in the visudo file and has execute rights, the user of the script is www-data.

```
./get_version /usr/sbin/apachectl 1     OUTPUT: 2.2.2
./get_version /usr/sbin/nginx 2         OUTPUT: 1.3
```

Can someone please explain why it does work in terminal but not in php?

Comment: Shouldn't you backslash `$` in double quotes in `print $2`?

Comment: Do you mean like this:  `print \$2` ? I tried it but then i get syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the problem and the solution. The command `whereis` in my php switch statement wrote a space character to the path variable for some unknown reason, so it did not worked because of it. I used `rtrim` on my `$path` variable to fix it.

```
    case "apache":
        $path   = shell_exec("whereis apachectl | awk '{ print $2 }'");
        $path   = rtrim($path);
        ...
```

Comment: Does it work now? Note also, that the error message you received, was *not* produced by `bash`, but by `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape `$` if you are using it inside double quotes in php or switch to single quotes:

```
...
$path   = shell_exec('whereis apachectl | awk \'{ print $2 }\'');
...
$path = shell_exec('whereis nginx | awk \'{ print $2 }\'');
```

Comment: Hmm. I used your code but unfortunately i still get the same error. I also think it makes no different to my code.

Comment: Please add debug output for `$path` and `$version` string and post in your question. `echo $path . "\n" . $version;` before `break` statement.

Comment: I get `/usr/sbin/apachectl` + `sh: 2: 1: not found` and `/usr/sbin/nginx` + `sh: 2: 2: not found`

Comment: If I set `$webroot` to `/my/web/root` I get `sudo /my/web/root/scripts/get_version whereis apachectl | awk '{ print $2 }' 1 2>&1` which seems to be fine...

Comment: Just a remark: You can simplify your script by using `which apachectl` instead of `whereis apachectl`. First will just return the path to the executable, no additional info.

Comment: Thanks for the `which` command, but for some reason it outputs nothing in my php code. Maybe i have to allow the command for www-data first. I also tried to set the webroot folder manual, but it does not work either, i still get the same `sh: 2: X` output

Comment: i found the solution, the command `whereis` wrote a space character to the path variable, so it did not worked because of it. I used `rtrim` on my `$path` variable, now it works :)